# Pandas dataframe one column values into columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have this input:

```
    user_id currency  amount
0         1      eur     570
1         2      btc     510
2         2      eur     282
3         3      eur     822
4         3      usd     655
```

and would like to turn it into this output:

```
user_id   eur    btc    usd
1         570    0      0
2         282    510    0
3         822    0      655
```

Any ideas? thanks!